# Error in the generated proto file in grpc-web saying proto is not defined

Tags: nuxt.js, grpc-web

I am trying to run grpc-web with nuxtjs. The issue I am facing only happens when I run "npm run dev". Its not happening if I run "npm run start" ie, production mode.

I have included all the files and when I run it and try to access the webpage, it shows this error "proto is not defined." This error is coming from the generated proto files by the protoc command.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem when using the google/protobuf/timestamp.proto.In production it works fine but when using npm run dev it brings the error proto is not defined.
At the moment my work around for this issue is to set ssr false during development and then set ssr true(that is in nuxt.config.js) in production and this seems to resolve my issue.

Alternatively you can just make the proto object a string by simply adding quote to it that is change proto to "proto".
So far this works for me with no negative effect.